# Cannot find Module error when running on production server. ExpressJS

Tags: node.js, express

I'm working on Node JS using ExpressJS. Everything works fine when I run the service on my local. But when I move the code to the production server. I got this error,

> Error: Cannot find module '../controllers/SeatExcelcontroller'

Here is my route that call this controller,

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const SeatExcelController = require('../controllers/SeatExcelcontroller');

const seatExcelController = new SeatExcelController();

router.get('/paxlist/:program_id', seatExcelController.generateExcel);

module.exports = router;
```

Here is my project structure,

[image]

I really have no idea how to fix this because the path of the controller is correct and it can work on my local.

Please helps. Thanks a lot.

Comment: did u move the controller folder? How did u deploy? What is your start command like? deploy via docker? Heroku?

Comment: I find that if you're going from windows->linux or something, the directories are read differently. A single period may fix it.

Comment: @SomeoneSpecial Not doing something like that yet. Just directly run the app.js file

Comment: in the same environment?